# Scikit Learn Naive Bayes

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm new to scikit learn and I'm confused as to what this program is trying to predict.

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[-1, -1], 
          [-2, -1], 
          [-3, -2], 
          [1, 1], 
          [2, 1], 
          [3, 2]])
Y = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
clf = GaussianNB()
clf.fit(X, Y)

print(clf.predict([[-0.8, -1]]))
```

If I run this program I get:

```
[1]
```

As far as I can tell "X" is the training data and I'm not sure what "Y" is. If I change:

```
([[-0.8, -1]])
```

to

```
([[-0.8, 1]])
```

I get

```
[2]
```

I just need a little bit of it defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Y` is a training labels.
Function `predict` returns predicted label.